# How to display a Word document saved in database inside a web page

Tags: asp.net, sql-server, ms-word

I am converting and saving a word document to SQL Server database as varbinary. I can save the data. I want to display the uploaded Word document back to the user just like how a resume looks in Word, as if the actual Word document was embedded in the web page itself.

I have the below code, which is downloading the saved Word document as a Word file. Please tell me which is the best control to display the word document also inside the browser.

```
 byte[] fileContent = new byte[fuResume.PostedFile.ContentLength];
            fuResume.PostedFile.InputStream.Read(fileContent, 0, fuResume.PostedFile.ContentLength);
            //lblAppliedMessage.Text = ByteArrayToString(fileContent);

            //lblAppliedMessage.Text = BitConverter.ToString(fileContent).Replace("-", string.Empty);


            byte[] btYourDoc;
            btYourDoc = fileContent;
            Response.ContentType = "application/ms-word";
            Response.AddHeader("Content-Disposition",
            "inline;filename=yourfilename.doc");


            Response.BinaryWrite(btYourDoc);
            Response.End();
```

Answer (score 0):

Provided that you have word on the web server or on the application server, I would save to a temp file the stream coming from the database, open it with word, save as html and render this html in the web browser.

**Edit:**

as mentioned in the link provided in the comment: http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;257757 you should possibly avoid usage of Word/Excel Automation on server side code, here an extract from this article from MS:

> Microsoft does not currently recommend, and does not support,
>   Automation of Microsoft Office applications from any unattended,
>   non-interactive client application or component (including ASP,
>   ASP.NET, DCOM, and NT Services), because Office may exhibit unstable
>   behavior and/or deadlock when Office is run in this environment.

Suggested solutions/alternatives are:

[Word Automation Services Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ee558830.aspx)

[Excel Services Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms546696.aspx)

Comment: Microsoft specifically says you shouldn't install Microsoft Office on a server as it has issues with memory leaks when run over a long period of time.

Comment: @rtpHarry can you please send a link of this statement from Microsoft? If you dispose and release office objects after usage I think either this is not the cause of leaks are minimal anyway. I have never seen the article you are mentioning (but not linking yet), in any case isn't the memory released once word is closed or IIS app pool recycled?

Comment: sure, the link is here http://support.microsoft.com/default.aspx?scid=kb;EN-US;257757